# Não abre apenas o post pelo id

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém pode dar uma ajudinha, por favor?
Quando aperto em um post do meu blog, deveria mostrar apenas aquele post em outra página. Mas não estou conseguindo mostrar esse post. Para todos que eu abro, está mostrando sempre as informações iguais e a mesma foto.

index.php

```
<?php require_once('conn.php');

$consulta_categoria = mysql_query("SELECT Posts.titulo_principal, 
       Posts.data, 
       Posts.descricao,
       Categorias.categoria,
       Posts.texto_inicial,
       Posts.texto_secundario,
       Posts.titulo_principal,
       Posts.imagem1,
       Posts.imagem1_dir,
       Posts.imagem2,
       Posts.imagem2_dir
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Categorias ON Categorias.id = Posts.categoria_id ORDER BY Posts.id DESC");
$linha_categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_categoria);

$consulta_menu = "SELECT id, categoria FROM categorias order by categoria asc";
$resultado_menu = mysql_query($consulta_menu, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$linhas_menu = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_menu);

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conn) or die(mysqli_error());
$linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);

$consulta_recentes = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$resultado_recentes = mysql_query($consulta_recentes, $conn) or die(mysqli_error());
$linhas_recentes = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_recentes);

?>


<div class="blog-post">
                    <?php do {  ?>

                    <div class="post-thumb">
                        <a href="#"><img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/post/imagem1/<?php echo $linha_categoria['imagem1_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linha_categoria['imagem1']; ?>"></a>
                        <div class="hover-wrap">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="post-content">

                        <h6 class="post-title"><a href="post-detalhe.php?idpost=<?php echo $linhas['id'] ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['titulo_principal']); ?></a></h6>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="meta-part"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></i><?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['categoria']); ?></a></span>
                            <span class="meta-part"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> <?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['data']); ?></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <p><?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['descricao']); ?></p></p>
                        <a href="post-detalhe.php?idpost=<?php echo $linhas['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-common btn-rm">Leia Mais</a>
                    </div>

                <?php } while ($linha_categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_categoria));  ?>

                </div>
```

---

post-detalhe.php

```
<?php require_once('conn.php');

$id = (int)$_GET['idpost'];
$resultado_post = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ' . $id, $conn);
$linhas_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_post);

$consulta_menu = "SELECT id, categoria FROM categorias order by categoria asc";
$resultado_menu = mysql_query($consulta_menu, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$linhas_menu = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_menu);

?>
```

Abaixo é o código onde mostra as informações do post, na página post-detalhe.php:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-xs-12">

                <div class="blog-post single-post">

                    <div class="post-thumb">
                        <a href="#"><img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/post/imagem1/<?php echo $linhas_post['imagem1_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas_post['imagem1']; ?>"></a>
                        <div class="hover-wrap">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="post-content">
                        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="#"><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas_post['titulo_principal']); ?></a></h4>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="meta-part"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i> <?php echo $linhas_post['categoria']; ?></a></span>
                            <span class="meta-part"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> <?php echo utf8_encode($linhas_post['data']); ?></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <p><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas_post['texto_inicial']); ?></p>
                        <br>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/post/imagem2/<?php echo $linhas_post['imagem2_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas_post['imagem2']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <p><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas_post['texto_secundario']); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Meu código deve estar errado, mas não sei onde estou errando. Alguém pra ajudar?
Obrigada!

Comment: Por esse códigos,parece não haver problema. O numero do id está alterando em cada registro realmente? Veja se toda vez que você clica em um post em "leia mais" o id é alterado na url.

Comment: Oi Andrei, acabei de ver aqui e o id não está alterando. Está repetindo sempre o mesmo id, ou seja, está repetindo o último id cadastrado no banco de dados.

Como faço para mostrar o id certo e o post daquele id?

Comment: Coloque o código que você gera essa lista ai na pergunta. Que eu vejo se eu encontro alguma coisa...

Comment: Ali no arquivo index tem só uma parte do código... o problema está por ali...

Comment: Prontinho, creio que seja isso. Alterei o index.php

Comment: Está la a resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A solução encontrada pela próprio OP foi que no select não havia o
>   campo de id.

Utilize a variável que foi criada no loop `$linha_categoria`, iniciando por ele:

```
<div class="blog-post">
        <?php while ($linha_categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_categoria)) {  ?>

        <div class="post-thumb">
            <a href="#"><img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/post/imagem1/<?php echo $linha_categoria['imagem1_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linha_categoria['imagem1']; ?>"></a>
            <div class="hover-wrap">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="post-content">

            <h6 class="post-title"><a href="post-detalhe.php?idpost=<?php echo $linha_categoria['id'] ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['titulo_principal']); ?></a></h6>
            <div class="meta">
                <span class="meta-part"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></i><?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['categoria']); ?></a></span>
                <span class="meta-part"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> <?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['data']); ?></a></span>
            </div>
            <p><?php echo utf8_encode($linha_categoria['descricao']); ?></p></p>
            <a href="post-detalhe.php?idpost=<?php echo $linha_categoria['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-common btn-rm">Leia Mais</a>
        </div>

    <?php }  ?>

</div>
```

Com essas alterações seu código deve funcionar como esperado.

*Uma dica...*

Force o inteiro para o id assim:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['idpost'];
```

[Isso pode te ajudar a evitar injeções no banco.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php)

Comment: Mesmo usando $linha_categoria, ainda abre somente o último id.
http://localhost/Classic/post-detalhe.php?idpost=11
Só puxa o id 11, que é o último id cadastrado.

Comment: @MárciaPrates Coloca o SELECT na pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei todos os selects.

Comment: Isso, que quando aperte em Saiba mais, mostre o post daquele id.

Comment: @MárciaPrates fiz uma outra edição... encontrei todos os erros eu acho. Veja lá.

Comment: Vou ver se dá certo. Obrigada por estar me ajudando.

Comment: @MárciaPrates fiz mais uma alteração... parece que `Categorias` também é com letra minuscula.

Comment: eu consegui.
Acredita que foi uma falha minha mesmo?
A linha do select no index.php
$consulta_categoria = mysql_query("SELECT Posts.titulo_principal, faltou colocar o id. Por isso mostrava o mesmo id para todos os posts.

Comment: @MárciaPrates acontece! =)

Comment: Muito obrigada mesmo pela ajuda e pela disposição.
E me desculpa por te incomodar.

Comment: @MárciaPrates sem problemas! =)